# Change <SOAPAction>""</SOAPAction> on request recieved in WCF

Tags: wcf, wcf-configuration, .net-4.5.2, wcf-4

I have a WCF service implemented via custom wsdl. It simple have 5 methods as per wsdl. Call to My service from standard client works fine. Problem was in some old implementation which send `SoapAction=""` 
I wanted to change the `soapAction` to some value if i got empty. For that I have implemented `CustomBehavior` but even in it I can't able to hit `AfterReceiveRequest` method or any method in the behavior

```
 public class CustomInspectorBehavior : Attribute, IDispatchMessageInspector, 
        IClientMessageInspector, IEndpointBehavior, IServiceBehavior
```

Any idea i can response even if i have SOAPAction="" in the request

Edit 
My Service Looks like following

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "3.0.0.0")]
[System.ServiceModel.ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace="http://txnTest.Test.com", ConfigurationName="MyServiceTxnHost")]
public interface IMyServiceTxnHost
{

    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://txnTest.Test.com/IMyServiceTxnHost/payment")]
    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "*")]
    //[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    paymentResponse payment(paymentRequest request);

    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://txnTest.Test.com/IMyServiceTxnHost/commit")]
    //[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    commitResponse commit(commitRequest request);

    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://txnTest.Test.com/IMyServiceTxnHost/reserve")]
    //[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    reserveResponse reserve(reserveRequest request);

    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://txnTest.Test.com/IMyServiceTxnHost/cancel")]
    //[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    cancelResponse cancel(cancelRequest request);

    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://txnTest.Test.com/IMyServiceTxnHost/raise")]
    //[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    raiseResponse raise(raiseRequest request);


    //[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "*")]
    [System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action = "http://txnTest.Test.com/IMyServiceTxnHost/balance")]
    //[System.ServiceModel.XmlSerializerFormatAttribute(Style=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatStyle.Rpc, Use=System.ServiceModel.OperationFormatUse.Encoded)]
    balanceResponse balance(balanceRequest request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set OperationContract's property *Action* to "*" to associate every call which cannot reach its destination with specific method.

```
[OperationContract(Action = "*")]
void LostRequest();
```

Comment: Got Error
cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: A ServiceContract has more the one operation with an Action of "*".  A ServiceContract can have at most one operation an Action = "*"..]   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)

Comment: Also checking http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/remove-action-soap-header-165661.aspx but no use

Comment: Show service definition

Comment: Also seen a similar thing http://blog.michaelhidalgo.info/2012/10/is-soapaction-required-httpheader-to.html but no solution

Comment: I have added the definition above